# Azure Web App Authorization Issue when Embedding in Microsoft Team

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams, azure-webapps

I have a Webapp hosted on Azure that utilizes the /.auth/me, /.auth/refresh, and other endpoints for authorization. Everything functions smoothly in a standalone environment. However, when attempting to integrate this web app as a personal app within Microsoft Teams, I encounter an authorization issue accompanied by the error message:

"Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'."

I've attempted to add the domain to the allowed domains list, but this hasn't resolved the problem. Is there any workaround?

For example a code snippet / Recieves accessToken, userclaims and more.:

```html
/**
 * Retrieves user information from the server.
 *
 * @return {Promise<UserInfo[]>} An array of user information objects.
 */
export async function getUserInfo(): Promise<UserInfo[]> {
  const response = await fetch("/.auth/me");

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("No identity provider found. Access to chat will be blocked.");
    return [];
  }

  const payload = await response.json();
  return payload;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to launch your own authentication popups within Teams - your tab is a tightly-controlled iframe for security reasons. It's definitely possible to get authentication working, but you *have* to use the standard SSO approach (assuming you're doing 365 logins). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

Comment: Thx, i will take a look.